# How to enable bulk permission in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to insert images using "bulk" into SQL Server 2012. But, am ending up with the error message stating tha:

> Msg 4834, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.

I have "sysadmin" access.

Comment: It might help if you posted what generated the error...

Comment: How are you doing the bulk upload?  It's not necessarily using your login, depending on where you're performing the action.

Comment: Have you tried to set to BULKADMIN permission?

Comment: Are you sure that you have sysadmin as the user that you're running as? I ask because sysadmin is typically an "I can do anything" card on the server. Check with "exec xp_logininfo '<your login here>'"

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try `GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO [server_login]`. It is a server level permission, not a database level.  This has fixed a similar issue for me in that past (using OPENROWSET I believe).

Comment: There is a Server-level role called `[bulkadmin]` that does this. Rather than directly granting the right you could also add a user or group to that role. In SQL2012 that is `ALTER SERVER ROLE [bulkadmin] ADD MEMBER [USERNAME]` and in versions going back to at least SQL2000 you can use `EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'USERNAME', @rolename = N'bulkadmin'`

Comment: `Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.` -- expected. I suppose I can't just give myself access to anything I want!

Comment: Does this mean the Login must exist at Server level? Yes I think it does; the server level roles depends on having a **server**-level **login** (vs *database*-level *user*) Like the difference between [sp_add**srv**rolemember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addsrvrolemember-transact-sql) (which expects `@loginame`) and  [sp_addrolemember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql) (which expects `@membername`)

Comment: But is there a way to restrict this permission to specific databases?

Comment: I am trying to understand: the username for the bulk operation must be able to login into the Windows Server besides existing in the database under Security>logins?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```sql
USE master;

GO;
 
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO shira;
```

Answer (score 7):

**Note that the accepted answer or either of these two solutions work for Windows only.**

```sql
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO [login_name];
-- OR
ALTER SERVER ROLE [bulkadmin] ADD MEMBER [login_name];
```

If you run any of them on SQL Server based on a linux machine, you will get these errors:

```
Msg 16202, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Keyword or statement option 'bulkadmin' is not supported on the 'Linux' platform.
```

```
Msg 16202, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
Keyword or statement option 'ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS' is not supported on the 'Linux' platform.
```

Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions).

> Requires INSERT and ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permissions. In Azure
> SQL Database, INSERT and ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS
> permissions are required. ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permissions or
> the bulkadmin role is not supported for SQL Server on Linux. Only the
> sysadmin can perform bulk inserts for SQL Server on Linux.

**Solution for Linux**

```sql
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [login_name];
```

Comment: Great Answer! this worked for me since I was using Linux.

Answer (score 3):

If you get an error saying "Cannot Bulk load file because you don't have access right"

First make sure the path and file name you have given are correct.

then try giving the bulkadmin role to the user. To do so follow the steps :- 
In Object Explorer -> Security -> Logins -> Select the user (right click) -> Properties  -> Server Roles -> check the bulkadmin checkbox -> OK.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server may also return this error if the service account does not have permission to read the file being imported. Ensure that the service account has read access to the file location. For example:

`icacls D:\ImportFiles /Grant "NT Service\MSSQLServer":(OI)(CI)R`