# what to use instead of bulk load? Got error 'do not have permission to use the bulk load statement'

Tags: sql, ssms

I am trying to add a text file into SQL database table using BULK INSERT.
BULK
INSERT My_Tablename 
FROM 'C:\testing\temptest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
But got error that 'do not have permission to use the bulk load statement'.
Is there any alternative way to do it?
I don't want to set TRUSTWORTHY ON or create certificate for BULK admin permission.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604416/how-to-enable-bulk-permission-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Try using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

1. Right click on the database in in Object Explorer within SSMS.
2. Go to Tasks > Import Data
3. Select "Flat File Source" for your data source and follow the wizard to specify delimiters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although @SQLChao definitely has the answer, I did not remember the location of said `Import Data` option and simply opened the delimited file with my favorite text editor, `Notepad++` and did the following find and replaces with Search Mode set to extended:

1. Find: `'` Replace: `''`
2. Find: `|` Replace: `','`
3. Find: `\r\n` Replace: `')\r\n`
4. Find: `\r\n` Replace: `\r\nINSERT INTO [DB_Name].[Schema_Name].[Table_Name] VALUES(\r\n'`

The only issues should be in your first and last insert statements which can manually be edited as need be.

I then copied the text straight into Sql Server and executed.