# Alternate for dbwritetable to write tables from R to sql server

Tags: sql, r, sql-insert, rmysql

I have a local data frame of more than 4000 rows and around 10 columns. Currently using dbWriteTable function to write table into SQL server using R. But it is dead slow (takes more than 30 mins)
Is there any alternate approach for this using which I can do this faster?

Comment: SQL Server or MySql?

Comment: SQL Server it is

Comment: _Microsoft_ SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Consider exporting the dataframe to csv and run SQL Server's [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql):

```sql
BULK INSERT myNewTable
FROM 'C:\Path\To\File.csv'
WITH
  (
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',  
    TABLOCK
  )
```

Alternatively, save the csv into Excel format (.xlsx) or directly from R to Excel format and run a [distributed query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306397/how-to-use-excel-with-sql-server-linked-servers-and-distributed-querie) in a make-table action:

```sql
-- Adjust path and sheet name
SELECT * 
INTO myNewTable
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'Data Source=C:\Path\To\File.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...SheetName$ 


SELECT * 
INTO myNewTable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   'Data Source=C:\Path\To\File.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0', SheetName$)
```

Notes

- [Bulk operations must be granted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604416/how-to-enable-bulk-permission-in-sql-server) to user calling the action which is a server-level right and not database-level. Consequently, you may not be able to run command through R but in SSMS console.
- [Ad Hoc Distributed queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569(v=sql.110).aspx) must be enabled on database to connect to remote data sources that use OLE DB.
- Distributed queries assume you have SQL Server and MS Office in same bit-architecture: both at 64-bit installs with Access engine installed. If not, free MS 2007/2010/2013/2016 download are available. See [2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920). If SQL Server is on 32-bit, use older `Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0` and save Excel file in older `.xls` format with properties as `Excel 8.0`.