# How to allow non-admin user to use BULK INSERT on Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert

I am currently struggling to get `BULK INSERT` working on an Azure SQL Database *without* using the admin user. The following script works fine and exactly as expected and [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) when executed by the admin user:

```
-- Note: this requires a MASTER KEY to exist!
-- If you don't have a master key yet, create one with the following statement:
--CREATE MASTER KEY;

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL StorageCredential WITH
    IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
    SECRET = '<my-blob-storage-sas>';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE StorageContainerDataSource WITH (
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://<blob-storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net/bulk',
    CREDENTIAL = StorageCredential
);

CREATE TABLE [#TestFacts] (
    [Id] uniqueidentifier,
    [MachineId] uniqueidentifier,
    [TimeZone] nvarchar(50),
    [SliceDate] datetime2(7),
    [SliceTimeStamp] datetime2(7),
    [Weight] bigint,
    [UserId] uniqueidentifier,
    [Longitude] float,
    [Latitude] float
);

BULK INSERT [#TestFacts]
FROM 'test.csv'
WITH (
    DATA_SOURCE = 'StorageContainerDataSource',
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
    KEEPIDENTITY,
    KEEPNULLS
);

DROP TABLE [#TestFacts];
DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE StorageContainerDataSource;
DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL StorageCredential;
```

When executing this as a non-admin user, which has been granted SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT, ALTER, CONTROL and ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS, I get the following error message:

```
Msg 4834, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.
```

According to the documentation, it should be sufficient to have the permissions INSERT, ALTER and, most importantly, ADMINISTER *DATABASE* BULK OPERATIONS. But when checking the database permissions (in `sys.database_permissions`) I can see that `GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS TO myUser` added the following row:

```
principal_id  name    type_desc  authentication_type_desc  class_desc  type  permission_name  state_desc  major_id  minor_id
6             myUser  SQL_USER   DATABASE                  DATABASE          NULL             GRANT       0         0
```

Note that type is empty and permission_name is NULL! According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-permissions-transact-sql), this should be `DABO` and `ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS`.

So my questions right now are: Is this a bug in Azure SQL Database? Is there something I forgot to do? Is BULK INSERT actually not supported for non-admin users?

Some notes:

- The `@@VERSION` is "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jan 26
  2018 23:35:00" and `SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')` is "5".
- All resources I found on similar issues talk about SQL Server, where you either need to have the role `bulkadmin` or need to grant ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS (note that DATABASE is missing there!) to the user. But Azure SQL Database has neither.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604416/how-to-enable-bulk-permission-in-sql-server.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example on the Microsoft github account](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/features/sql-bulk-load/load-from-azure-blob-storage/LoadFromAzureBlobStorage.sql) which contains a very important piece of information:

> Create a permanent table.  A temp table currently is not supported for
>   BULK INSERT, although it will will work with OPENROWSET

So the problem can be resolved by removing the `#` from the table name, to make it a permanent table. Then everything works as expected and documented, even for non-admin users.

Note: The quote from the example reads as if inserting into a temporary table would be possible with OPENROWSET (e.g. `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ...) AS bulk`), but testing that results in the same error as BULK INSERT!