# Azure Sql Database Restore to Local error on Bulk Admin permission mismatch

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

When trying to restore an Azure Sql database either by Import Data Tier Application or Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database options I get the following error:

> Could not import package.
> Warning SQL72012: The object [database_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
> Warning SQL72012: The object [database_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 4632, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The permission 'ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS' is not supported in this version of SQL Server. Alternatively, use the server level 'ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS' permission.
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
> GRANT Administer Database Bulk Operations TO [zzzz];

This results in the schema being loaded but no data restored. I tried this on both Sql Server Developer Edition 2019 and 2022 with SSMS 18.9 and 19.1.

Is there any way to work around this disconnect to get the data restored?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), "`ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS` applies to: SQL Database." Here, SQL database refers to Azure SQL Database. It does not support databases on Windows or Linux OS. This might be the reason for the error while importing a data tier application. If the database is on Linux, add the following script to the backpack file:

```sql
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [login_name];
```

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604416/how-to-enable-bulk-permission-in-sql-server/63752006#63752006).